# How can I typeset those three mathematical symbols?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I need to typeset (in one of my post on [Mathematics.SX](http://math.stackexchange.com)) the following three mathematical symbols but I don't know how:

1. the symbol for the [Heaviside function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function),
2. the symbol for "not equal", as in "x not equal to 0",
3. the symbol for a partial derivative.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: You really need to be more precise about what you want.  However, for finding concrete symbols try http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/15925

Comment: Partial derivative operator symbol: `\partial` ;-) Heaviside function symbol is normally the upcase `\Theta` . Not equal: `\neq`. I don't know, whether they work in Math.SX

Comment: I dont get what u mean by  upcase \Theta. Could u please explain. Thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Please note that Math.SE uses MathJaX, which is not exactly LaTeX. I believe that most relevant stuff is available in [Math.SE's MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), the list includes all of greek letters, `\neq` and `\partial` :)

Comment: As far as I know (unless there are several Heaviside functions) the most common notation is simply `H`, others include `u` (unit step function) or `θ`. Never see `Θ`. For partial derivatives, I would recommend the `esdiff` package, which has handy macros for typetting partial derivatives of any order.

Comment: @Bernard An answer?

Comment: @Jubobs: Yes, this package might be of help for other users. Let me time to add an example…

Comment: @Jubobs: I can't add an example with `esdiff` as the post has been closed and the mentioned link is not relevant to include it. Do you know how one can ask for re-opening it?

Comment: @Bernard I voted to reooen it. Wait for four other people to do the same and you should be able to post an answer.

Comment: @yswong: You can draw the symbol on http://write-math.com/classify/ and share a link / embed the image here. Eventually it will also directly tell you what the symbol is. (I'm still working on it.)

Comment: I think this question should be deleted. The title is useless and I don't see a way to fix it. Eventually you could open 3 new questions, one for each symbol with a better title. But I don't think that makes sense. In future, you might eventually want to try http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends

Comment: @moose: I agree with you, as the OP did not manage to show up and add more information. I voted for close earlier, but it was reopened :/

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I did not vote for close, but I flagged it. I don't want it to be closed. Closed questions should contribute something (like another way to describe a problem and hence making it easier for others to google for it). This question (as it is stated) is useless for others. So to all moderators who read this: Please delete it!

Comment: @moose: Private opinion: The question stands as a bad example ;-)

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know (unless there are several Heaviside functions) the most common notation is simply H, others include u (unit step function) or θ (`\theta`). Never seen Θ (`\Theta`). For partial derivatives, I would recommend the `esdiff` package, which has handy macros for typesetting partial derivatives of any order.

Here is an example with the `esdiff` package:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[thinc]{esdiff}

\DeclareMathOperator{\Heavi}{H}

\begin{document}

    \[ \diff{(\Heavi(x))}{x} = \delta(x) ,\qquad \diff[2]{(\sin x)}{x} = -\sin x , \qquad \diff*{\mathrm{e}^x}{x}{0} = 1 \]%

    \[ \diffp{f}{{x^2}{y^3}},\qquad \diffp*{f}{{x^2}{y^3}}{(0,0)} \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]